# How to sort MySQL by two columns?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I made a music blog with a few friends and I made a MySQL table to keep track of post views. I have one column to keep track of admin views and one column keep track of user views for each post.

I am making a page to easily view and sort by most admin views, most user views, and total views. I did not make a column for "total views" in my MySQL database (To calculate, I just add the admin views to the user views. Plain and simple).

I can easily sort by admin views by querying `SELECT * FROM log ORDER BY ADMIN DESC` and the same for user views, but is there a simple way to do something like `SELECT * FROM log ORDER BY ADMIN + USER DESC`? If not, I will have to mess with my code to provide my own sorting algorithm.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: This is easily solved with a quick Google search.

Comment: What is the datatype of ADMIN or USER views?

Comment: just to clarify: you want to `ORDER BY` total views?

Comment: I sometimes wonder why people do not try their code first.

Answer (score 5):

The query is exactly as you put it:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    log
ORDER BY
        admin + user DESC
```

If you created a separate column for total views and indexed it, you could use it in a query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    log
ORDER BY
        total_views DESC
LIMIT   10
```

which would improve the `SELECT` speed for limited queries. The way you do it, the whole table should be scanned and ordered, even if you only select top 10 comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use the total views for anything besides sorting, I suggest:

```
SELECT *,(`admin`+`user`) as `total` FROM `log` ORDER BY `total` DESC
```

This will add a "total" field to your result which you can display or use in calculations.